# Check value of non-existent node - Firebase Database Rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am writing a rule where you can only write to a node if the counter of another node is less than 5 or does not exist at all.

I have tried this, but keep getting permission_denied:

```
//                                                                             payment needs to be set                                            one of these two has to evaluate to true
".write": "!data.exists() && root.child('allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/paymentDetails').exists() && (root.child('allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/activeJobCounter').val() <= 5 || !root.child('allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/activeJobCounter').exists())
```

There are no parent nodes with `.write` rules above this one.

The node at:

`'allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/activeJobCounter'`

does not exist when a user is created but it gets created once a user uploads a job.

So after creating a job it will say:

`'allUsers/serviceUsers/' + auth.uid + '/activeJobCounter = 1'`

This is why I want to allow writes to a particular node if the user has NONE (non-existent node) OR LESS THAN 5 jobs.

I really have no clue how to debug the security rules other than retrying and not getting the `permission_denied` message.

Comment: `!data.exists()` checks if there is data written already to that node, if the node you are writing to has old data then that permission will be denied. Is the write a new create?

Comment: Yes this is a new create, which is why this is so weird.